# Verbo per descrivere movimento di liquidi in un recipiente

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, verbs

Sto cercando di scrivere un testo in cui vorrei descrivere il movimento di un liquido (birra) nello stomaco del protagonista al suo risveglio dopo una "notte brava".

Sciabordare è uno dei pochi che al momento mi viene in mente.

Esempio:
"... E ancora poteva sentire la birra [sciabordare??] nel ventre dopo la folle serata... "

Esiste un verbo più appropriato di *sciabordare*?

Comment: C'è un refuso in «la file serata»?

Comment: Si hai ragione, intendevo folle serata. Ora correggo, grazie

Comment: Per la mia sensibilità, *sciabordare* si riferisce a contesti diversi (tipicamente l'acqua del mare). Io qui userei *gorgogliare*.

Comment: Grazie del consiglio, mette in luce altre possibilità semantiche.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Sciabordare* significa «[c]on riferimento ad acqua o altri liquidi, frangersi, battere ripetutamente contro un ostacolo, producendo un caratteristico rumore continuato» (*Treccani*, «[Sciabordare](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/sciabordare/)»). Si presta dunque a descrivere la condizione di chi si risvegli coi postumi di una sbornia e lo stomaco ancora pieno di birra.

Altre parole di significato affine sono *[sciaguattare](http://dizionario.internazionale.it/parola/sciaguattare)*, toscanismo molto espressivo che si riferisce a liquidi e significa «agitarsi in un recipiente» (*De Mauro*, «Sciaguattare»), *sguazzare* (ma in quest’accezione non è comune, cfr. *De Mauro*, «[Sguazzare](http://dizionario.internazionale.it/parola/sguazzare)», acc. 5) e *[diguazzare](http://dizionario.internazionale.it/parola/diguazzare)*, voce letteraria.

Comment: Grazie. Al link della treccani relativo a sciabordare leggo anche il sinonimo "rimescolare". Forse nell'esempio in esame si potrebbero anche usare altri termini che descrivono il ristagnare dell'acqua in un piccolo bacino(e.g. Stagno).

Comment: Di nulla. :-) La scelta della parola dipende dall’effetto che vuoi dare. In _sciaguattare_ personalmente avverto un’onomatopea («shhh… wah»), e per questo è un verbo che mi piace molto, benché non si senta in giro. L’effetto fonico non è da trascurare, a mio parere, in uno scritto letterario.